# why can not add string into javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I am try to add checkbox id into an array using language JavaScript,this is my code:

```
function checkBoxClick(e) {
    alert("a");
    var arr = new Array();
    var rule = new Array();
    var chkId = $(e).attr("id");
    var tempId = "";
    var tempElementId = "";
    $("input[class='singlechk']").each(function () {
        var elementId = $(this).attr("id");
        var larr = $(this).attr("id").split('-');
        tempElementId = elementId;
        if (tempId == "") {
            tempId = larr[0];
        } else {
            if (tempId != larr[0]) {
                rule.push(arr);
                arr = [];
                arr.push(tempElementId);
            } else {
                arr.push(tempElementId);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I am each every checkbox which class is "singlechk". Push the id into array arr,but everytime it aways add the last element,and the first element could not push into the array.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3 id="question_1">饭菜质量
        <span>（单选）</span>
    </h3>
    <br />
    <input name="wjdc" class="singlechk" id="item_1-1" type="checkbox" onclick="checkBoxClick(this)" />
    <span>一般</span>
    <br />
    <input name="wjdc" class="singlechk" id="item_1-2" type="checkbox" onclick="checkBoxClick(this)" />
    <span>很好</span>
    <h3 id="question_2">就餐环境
        <span>（单选）</span>
    </h3>
    <br />
    <input name="wjdc" class="singlechk" id="item_2-3" type="checkbox" onclick="checkBoxClick(this)" />
    <span>很好</span>
    <br />
    <input name="wjdc" class="singlechk" id="item_2-4" type="checkbox" onclick="checkBoxClick(this)" />
    <span>一般</span>
</div>
```

And this is the correct result it may be:

```
var rule = [["item_1-1", "item_1-2"], ["item_2-3", "item_2-4"]];
```

My question is:Why the array aways output

```
var rule = [["item_1-2"], ["item_2-4"]];
```

Comment: Why are you using `arr = [];`?

Comment: I want to empty the old array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is resetted in the `else` condition, and then a new item is `push`ed into it. So, at the end after loop finishes, array will contain only the last element.

Remove

```
arr = [];
```

Another thing is

```
rule.push(arr);
```

will push the complete array as an element inside the `rule` array.

To add the array elements inside another array use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```
rule.concat(arr);
```

Comment: Before reset,i have moved the array to another array rule

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```js
function checkBoxClick(e) {
  var rule = new Array(),
    tmp = {};
  $("input.singlechk:checked").each(function() {
    var elementId = this.id;
    var larr = elementId.split('-');
    if (!tmp[larr[0]]) {
      tmp[larr[0]] = [];
      rule.push(tmp[larr[0]]);
    }
    tmp[larr[0]].push(elementId);
  });
  snippet.log(JSON.stringify(rule))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h3 id="question_1">饭菜质量<span>（单选）</span></h3>
  <br />
  <input name="wjdc" class="singlechk" id="item_1-1" type="checkbox" onclick="checkBoxClick(this)" />
  <span>一般</span>
  <br />
  <input name="wjdc" class="singlechk" id="item_1-2" type="checkbox" onclick="checkBoxClick(this)" />
  <span>很好</span>
  <h3 id="question_2">就餐环境<span>（单选）</span></h3>
  <br />
  <input name="wjdc" class="singlechk" id="item_2-3" type="checkbox" onclick="checkBoxClick(this)" />
  <span>很好</span>
  <br />
  <input name="wjdc" class="singlechk" id="item_2-4" type="checkbox" onclick="checkBoxClick(this)" />
  <span>一般</span>
</div>
```